# T-SQL query runs in SQL Server Management Studio but not working in VB. NET application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I had this query running fine in my .NET app. I recently changed this to only query databases that are online. It works fine in SSMS and return the databases that contain the specified table with rows.

However when I use this back in the VB.NET app, the query returns 0 rows. Wondering if anyone can advise?

```
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  

 DECLARE @temptbl TABLE 
                  (
                      DBName varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                      EntryCOUNT integer
                  ) 

 DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(50)     

 SELECT @TableName = 'dbo.PRJMGTLocation'     
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)   
 
 SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT CHAR(13) + 'SELECT ''' + DB.name + ''', COUNT(1) FROM ' + DB.name + '.' + @TableName                  
                      FROM 
                          (SELECT TOP(1000) name FROM sys.databases  WHERE state = 0) DB                   
                      WHERE OBJECT_ID(DB.name + '.' + @TableName) IS NOT NULL                     
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')  
                
INSERT INTO @temptbl (DBName , EntryCOUNT)                 
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL   

SELECT * 
FROM @temptbl t 
WHERE EntryCOUNT >= 1
```

The .NET code is as shown below. I am passing the above SQL statement as `query2` variable:

```
Using cmdlocal1 As New OleDbCommand(query2, SQLSVRConn)
                                                        
    Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdlocal1)

        SQLSVRConn.Open()
        adapter.Fill(SqlDBTable)

        If SqlDBTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            SvrDBCBbox.DataSource = SqlDBTable

            SvrDBCBbox.ValueMember = "DBName"
            SvrDBCBbox.DisplayMember = "DBName"

        End If

        SQLSVRConn.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Better idea: generate the dynamic SQL from within VB _first_, then test that.

Comment: do you mean capture the SQL as it's assigned to the variable during debugging?

Comment: If you are using the same exact query in Visual Basic, then I'm surprised it would run at all. I would have expected it to treat your variable names as parameters since they're all prefixed with an `@` sign.

Comment: @David The OP's code isn't using parameters, they're just executing a batch statement, which is valid.

Comment: What kind of security are you using to connect to the database? Are you using SSPI or SQL Logins? If the latter, does the login have high enough permissions to query sys.databases? Are you definitely connecting to the right instance?

Comment: Is there an error or is literally returning nothing? I would nest you .net code in a try catch statement and print out the exception if there is one. This helps me determine if it's my query (sql) or if it's something I'm doing in side of .net.

Comment: @Dai - I guess I never tested that before. You're saying that you can use the `@` signs in a command string and it won't fail so long as you don't pass the command object any parameters?

Comment: Hi I am using SSPI in connection string. My login has SysAdmin rights on the instance. 
@anonymousCoder it returns 0 rows atadapter.fill line, whereas on the same instance if I run using SSMS I get list of databases having the table. also I am using try--catch statement but there isn't any error either.

Comment: @David Yes, that is correct. The syntax "`@foobar`" in T-SQL isn't just for `PROCEDURE` and `FUNCTION` parameters, but for all variables, including `DECLARE`-locals - and it's perfectly fine to use a multi-statement batch for `.CommandText`, you'll need to use `SqlDataReader` directly with `.NextResult()` for subsequent resultsets (I'm not a fan of `EtcDataAdapter` though: people overuse it imo when `EtcDataReader` is often better, but oh well).

Comment: Also make sure the connection used in the VB app has enough permissions for this.

Comment: And you're clearly connect to SQL Server (only database with the `FOR XML` syntax), so why are you using the OleDb provider instead of the SqlClient provider?

Comment: One more thought: put the code into a stored procedure and make VB call the procedure.

Comment: Hi guys, I think the issue was with using OleDBDataAdapter. somehow it wasn't working as expected. I changed the code to using SQLDataAdapter and now its working. What I noticed is that on the machine MS Access isn't launching properly as well. (We use some apps that need 64-bit MS Access to exist with 32 bit Office installation). I wonder these two issues are related.

Answer (score 2):

I found the same problem as you: query in SQL Server gets the result, but with OleDBDataAdapter it is empty. As a workaround the code below gets results for me:

```
Dim query2 As String = My.Resources.SQL
Dim sqlDBTable As New DataTable
Using SQLSVRConn As New OleDbConnection(strConn)
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand(query2, SQLSVRConn)
    SQLSVRConn.Open()
            Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                Dim cols As Int32
                If reader.Read Then
                    cols = reader.FieldCount
                    For i As Int32 = 0 To cols - 1
                        sqlDBTable.Columns.Add()
                    Next
                    Dim row As DataRow = sqlDBTable.Rows.Add
                    For i As Int32 = 0 To cols - 1
                        row.Item(i) = reader(i)
                    Next
                End If
                While reader.Read()
                    Dim row As DataRow = sqlDBTable.Rows.Add
                    For i As Int32 = 0 To cols - 1
                        row.Item(i) = reader(i)
                    Next
                End While
            End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Many thanks Xavier for testing and providing the code. This works great as I am getting the table populated with values.  Just later in the evening after reviewing in one of the comments, I changed the code to using SQLDataAdapter, and the code's now working as before. Thanks again...

Comment: Just to comment that my SQL Server edition is 64 bits, while MS Access (Office) is 32 bits.